# I want to use a code like the one I made in processing

Tags: html, css, processing, processing.js

I'm new to coding and I have a question.
I've made this simple code in processing and I was wondering if I could use it and how to do the same with an image inside a div.
  **This is the code:**

```java
<i>int  x, y;
PImage img;
void setup () {
  size(800, 739);

  img = loadImage("1.jpg");
}

void draw () {
  for (int i=0; i < mouseX/10; i ++) {
    int x = (int) random(width);  
    int y = (int) random(height);

    color cor = img.get(x, y);

    float t = random(5, 25);
    fill(cor, 30);
    noStroke ();
    ellipse(x, y, t, t);

  }
}
</i>
```

Comment: In HTML you need to use a `<canvas>` element, not a `<div>`

Comment: `<i>` and `</i>` are not valid in JavaScript.

Comment: Follow [processing.js tutorials/examples](http://processingjs.org/learning/). Obviously the way you tried it (by throwing `processing` code right into `HTML`) just can't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the location of the image (the `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag), then all you need to do is change this line:

```java
img = loadImage("1.jpg");
```

To something like this:

```java
img = loadImage("http://example.com/YourImageFile.jpg");
```

If you don't know the location of the image ahead of time, then there are ways to get the location of the image using JavaScript. Any JavaScript you write can call any Processing code you write, so you might have something like this in your Processing code:

```java
void setImageLocation(String location){
  img = loadImage(location);
}
```

Then all you need to do is write JavaScript that gets the location of the image and calls that function.

Check out the [Accessing Processing from JavaScript](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html#accessingprocessingfromjs) section of the Processing.js tutorial for more info.